# Dynamic ListView OnItemClick - Should populate values in another activity

Tags: android, android-listview

Android 2.3.3

I have two activities, Home and History. I have a dynamic listview(Using custom adapter) in history and I have data in the listview. When an item is clicked, the values in the item are supposed to reflect in the home activity(a textview and an edittext should be populated).

Below is the code...

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     TextView txtExp = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txtView_History_Expression);
     TextView txtRes = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txtView_History_Result);

     String ret_Exp = txtExp.getText().toString();
     String ret_Res = txtRes.getText().toString();

     System.out.println("exp = "+ret_Exp+"   res = "+ret_Res);

     ma = new MainActivity();
     TextView ma_prev = (TextView) ma.findViewById(R.id.txtViewPrevious);
     EditText ma_Res = (EditText) ma.findViewById(R.id.edtxtInput);

     ma_prev.setText("");
     ma_prev.setText(ret_Exp);

     ma_Res.setText("");
     ma_Res.setText(ret_Res);

    }
```

I get a nullpointer exception when I use the above code...

```
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at com.mobilevoiceapps.advancedvoicecalculatorfree.History.onItemClick(History.java:207)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3744)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1991)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
03-17 14:39:42.199: E/AndroidRuntime(20411):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the XML for the listview row ::::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Count"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:text="Number"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Result"
            android:textColor="#316DA2"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Expression"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Expression"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't think I am doing it the correct way. Can someone tell me how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ma = new MainActivity();
TextView ma_prev = (TextView) ma.findViewById(R.id.txtViewPrevious);
EditText ma_Res = (EditText) ma.findViewById(R.id.edtxtInput);
```

It won't work this way in Android. You should create an `Intent` for the `MainActivity`, put the data you want to pass inside an extras `Bundle` and call `startActivity()` to create the `MainActivity`. Then you should retrieve data from the incoming `Bundle` inside the `MainActivity's` `onCreate()` and populate your views with it.